# How to make created html templates downloadable to clients?

Tags: file-sharing

I have created templates for a company's website that I am working on. I have three different folder each folder containing different styles. I am trying to find a tool where I can put the files on, and then send a link or whatever to my client so that he can see the templates that I have created. Is there any tool out there where I can do this..? Besides a flashdrive...

Answer (score 0):

Try Dropbox. You can either create a folder and "share" it, or just send a link via email to the folder to the client.